Android R8 ProGuard
I'm trying to understand some strange behavior related to R8.
R8 rules her
What i have:
class MyUseCase @Inject constructor(
    param1,
    param2,
) {

    suspend fun foo(): Response? {
        
            val request = MyDateRequest(param1 = param1)
            val wrapped = cloudApi.get().foo2(request)
        
    }
}

By some reason when i build signed apk (obfuscation, shrinks resource turned on)
The R8 wiped out class MyDateRequest and i have to add annotation @Keep to make it work
Why? I have explicit call to constructor.

You probably have to take a closer look at how much of MyUseCase is left in the program. I suggest using -dontobfuscate and maybe also -dontoptimize to first look at the effect of only shrinking (dead code removal). You can use apktool to decompile the APK and inspect the remaining code.

Not sure how it can help. MyUseCase - is singleton created by Hilt.

Alternatively you can open an issue with R8 at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 and include a small reproduction of possible.
